# Twitter Feed Reader

Tags: python, api, twitter, hashtag

I just read this gizmodo article about converting a label printer into a hashtag checker/printer.

http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/10/hack-a-label-printer-into-a-twitter-hashtag-ticker/

While the hardware is cool, I'd like to understand the Twitter API. How would I do the same for tweets from a user, and using Python?

Thanks!

Max

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest you start by reading one of the many python twitter libraries.  I have used the following one before http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

After that you just need a thread and a timer.

Answer (score 0):

The [Twitter developer documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs) is quite comprehensive and good.